# Code Coverage Issue while validation

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, metadata

How to find each class coverage for that current jobId which has been validated with only error, code coverage?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by jobId in the context of code coverage?

Comment: When we run a validation/ deployment request we get a jobId for that process/ operation. Suppose one such validation consist some new classes/ test classes or modified ones. How I'll get to know coverage for each class  including all components being validated

Comment: You could see that by running the test class from developer console in the source org.

Answer (score 0):

once you have run the validation, log into the target org where the validation took place, open the developer console and select on the bottom "tests".
as the validation just went over the testclasses, the small window on the bottom right will tell you the coverage of each class / trigger
if you select one of them, it will open up in the main screen and showing you in red / blue what is covered and what not.

But please , do NOT only code cover, also Test the code and verify with system assert.

Comment: I had checked the same but this will only display the code coverage for existing code. And it become zero after validations